# How can I conditionally run the Sequelize seed data command in docker compose up with a variable in package.json(or somewhere else)?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I have setup my nodejs + mysql rest-api with sequelize orm and installed in docker-compose. The  script part of my package.json is as follow:

```
"scripts": {
    "babel": "babel",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "migration": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "seed": "npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
    "start": "",
    "check-types": "tsc",
    "babel:node": "./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets=@babel/env --extensions '.js,.ts'",
    "dev": "npm run migration && npm run seed && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts"
}
```

And I have `CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]` in my `DockerFile` which will run the `dev` script. However, I want to conditionally run the seed command according to a variable I provided in `package.json`, I am expecting something like:

```
"scripts": {
    ..., // same as above
    "enableSeed": true,
    "dev": `npm run migration ${enableSeed? "&& npm run seed" : ""} && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts`
}
```

But this is not gonna work due to syntax, any solution to achieve this?

### UPDATE 1

Tried this according to @slideshowp2 's suggestion

```
"dev-seed": "npm run migration && npm run seed-reset && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts"
"dev-no-seed": "npm run migration && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts"
"ENABLE_SEED": "false"
"dev": "if [[ ${npm_package_scripts_ENABLE_SEED} == \"true\" ]]; then echo 'dev-seed'; else echo 'dev-no-seed'; fi"
```

But I received

```
sh: 1: [[: not found
```

which seem to mean `dev-no-seed` is not found

### UPDATE 2

I actually come up with a out of box solution like this:

```
{
  "seed": "npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
  "unseed": "npx sequelize-cli db:seed:undo:all",
  "seed-reset": "npm run unseed && npm run seed ",
  "dev-seed": "npm run migration && npm run seed-reset && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts",
  "dev-no-seed": "npm run migration && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts",
  "dev": "npm run dev-no-seed" // <----switch between dev-seed and dev-no-seed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional statements of shell script based on the value of environment variables. E.g.

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "if [[ ${ENABLE_SEED} == \"true\" ]]; then echo 'migration' && echo 'seed' && echo 'nodemon'; else echo 'migration' && echo 'nodemon'; fi"
  },
```

`npm run dev`:

```sh
> if [[ ${ENABLE_SEED} == "true" ]]; then echo 'migration' && echo 'seed' && echo 'nodemon'; else echo 'migration' && echo 'nodemon'; fi

migration
nodemon
```

Enable seed, run `ENABLE_SEED=true npm run dev`:

```sh
> if [[ ${ENABLE_SEED} == "true" ]]; then echo 'migration' && echo 'seed' && echo 'nodemon'; else echo 'migration' && echo 'nodemon'; fi

migration
seed
nodemon
```

Or, you can run the npm script based on the value of variables defined in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "ENABLE_SEED": "false",
    "dev": "if [[ ${npm_package_scripts_ENABLE_SEED} == \"true\" ]]; then echo 'migration' && echo 'seed' && echo 'nodemon'; else echo 'migration' && echo 'nodemon'; fi"
  },
```

With `ENABLE_SEED=false`, Run `npm run dev`:

```js
> if [[ ${npm_package_scripts_ENABLE_SEED} == "true" ]]; then echo 'migration' && echo 'seed' && echo 'nodemon'; else echo 'migration' && echo 'nodemon'; fi

migration
nodemon
```

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "ENABLE_SEED": "true",
    "dev": "if [[ ${npm_package_scripts_ENABLE_SEED} == \"true\" ]]; then echo 'migration' && echo 'seed' && echo 'nodemon'; else echo 'migration' && echo 'nodemon'; fi"
  },
```

With `ENABLE_SEED=true`, run `npm run dev`:

```sh
> if [[ ${npm_package_scripts_ENABLE_SEED} == "true" ]]; then echo 'migration' && echo 'seed' && echo 'nodemon'; else echo 'migration' && echo 'nodemon'; fi

migration
seed
nodemon
```

The rule of referencing the variable defined in `package.json` is `npm_package_<namespace>_Your custom variable`.

In this case, the `namespace` is `scripts`. So we can reference `ENABLE_SEED` using `npm_package_scripts_ENABLE_SEED`.

If the shell script becomes more complex, you'd better extract them into a `.sh` file.

Comment: I tried to define `"dev-seed": "npm run migration && npm run seed-reset && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts"` and ` "dev-no-seed": "npm run migration && nodemon --exec npm run babel:node -- app.ts" and used the script you suggested with `"ENABLE_SEED": "false"` like this `"dev": "if [[ ${npm_package_scripts_ENABLE_SEED} == \"true\" ]]; then echo 'dev-seed'; else echo 'dev-no-seed'; fi"`

Comment: and I'm getting `sh: 1: [[: not found` which means `dev-no-seed` is not found